# Docker - join multiple separate apps

Tags: docker

I have one (master) app that I decided to split between few separate apps (microservices). Each one has it's own repo, code base, stack and docker files.

Example:
Inventory app, that's composed of collection of separate microservices:

- api driven front app
- users service, that talks with every other service
- inventory service, which talks to app service
- reports service, which talks to inventory service.

I've spend several hours on searching the web for solution on how to link this together. Unfortunately only thing that I found are tutorials for using `docker file` and `docker compose`.  They are great, but they live in single app scope, not above it, in loosely coupled microservices scope. 
Is this even doable?

How can I have each microservice talk to the other services without hard-coding IP adresses and ports.

Comment: You don't mean the `--link=...` option (cf. https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/), right? What do you mean by "*link*"? Network connectivity? Shared filesystem? A script which creates several docker images out of one project and generates a wrapper script for running all the stuff?

Comment: @corny no, I'm talking about completely separate apps, that make one complete product. For example front app is done in angular by one team with its own infrastructure, reports app made in python by another team on its on infrastructure and so on.

Comment: Is your question on how to make microservices talk to each other or how to run things in Docker? Whether you run in Docker or not shouldn't matter on how your app works.

Comment: My question is about how to make microservices talk to each other without port juggling and hard-coded ip's :)

Answer (score 1):

There at least two ways this can be done:
 - Manual approach using `docker run ... --link ...` 
 - `docker-compose` with a configuration file showing how the apps are linked.

Either way is really just the `--link` option in use. [There is an example of a PostgreSQL server with container linking in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/#/using-container-linking).

[The documentation on how to do this with Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) also includes examples of linking.

What you need to understand is this: Let's say you link your inventory service to your app service, you would do something like `--link app` when starting the inventory service. From the inventory service container, you can access the app service simply with the name `app`. So `curl http://app` will go to your app container - no need to know an IP address. If your app service is not public to the world, you don't even need to map its port with the `-p` option because the networking from inventory to app service is all internal.

Comment: This only works for locally deployed containers. They have to be on the same machine and on the same overlay network. Anything different won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have everthing distributed, you need to use a clustering solution. You can use docker swarm which takes care of the networking issues you might face.
You could deploy your containers to a bunch of Amazon EC2 machines and use a load balancer in front of them, or use a DNS mapper. Either way, you have to go past your local dev env.

From my experience you cannot use container links between containers deployed on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--link`  for that even in compose file or as a command line argument.

In my opinion best option for this architecture is using *docker network* and *dns* with *environment variables*

You can find a lot of examples for similar architecture